# Logistic differential equation problem

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm taking the AP Calculus BC Exam next week and ran into this problem with no idea how to solve it. Unfortunately, the answer key didn't provide any explanations.

I'm having trouble turning the differential equation into a normal equation. A step-by-step explanation would be wonderful.

**The population P(t) of a species satisfies the logistic differential equation dP/dt = P(224 - (P^2)/56) where the initial population P(0) = 30 and t is the time in years. What is the limit of P(t) as t approaches infinity? (Calculator allowed)**

Comment: To solve the DE, we could use partial fractions. However, one should be able to answer the question without solving the DE.

Comment: That's what I thought too! Isn't 224 the limit?

Comment: If I am reading the numbers correctly it is $112$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the population has a logistic form, at long times (large t), the population reaches a steady state. Thus $dP/dt = 0$ as t approaches infinity.

Solving for P yields $\pm 112$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is a autonomous differential equation. With $p=0$ and $p=\pm \sqrt{224\cdot 56}=\pm112$ as trivial constant solutions. Draw an approximate plot (look up how to draw solutions for autonomous differential equations) of the solutions and see what happens for different initial values for $t \to \infty$.